# Java String.contains() to take care of natural numbers

Tags: java, regex, string, integer

I'm a computer science student learning Java, and as an exercise, we're doing a permutation algorhythm.

Now, i'm stuck at a point where i need to search for a natural number within a String full of numbers, splitted by a comma:

```
String myString = "0,1,2,10,14,";
```

The problem is i'm using...

```
myString.contains(String.valueOf(anInteger);
```

...to check for the presence of a specific number. This works for numbers from 0 to 9, but when looking for a more-than-1-digit number, the program does not recognize it as a natural number.

In other words, and as an example: "14" is not the integer 14, its just a string with an "1", and a "4"; so, if i run...

```
String myString = "0,1,2,10,14,";
if (myString.contains(myString.valueOf(4))) { doSomething(); }
```

...the "if" statement will be true, since the integer "4" is present in the string, as part of the natural number "14".

At this point, i've been searching through StackOverflow and other pages for a solution, and learnt i should use Pattern and Matcher.

My question is: what's the best way to do use them?

Relevant part of my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i<r; i++)
    {
    if (!act.contains(String.valueOf(i)))
        {
        ...
        }
    ...
    }
```

I use this method several times in my code, so an exact substitution would be nice.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: You could first split the string `String[] numbers = myString.split(",");` - that should make the rest easier.

Comment: Yep, but i was thinking in a Regex that should fit in, instead of additional "for" loops looking inside a String[], since the program is a permutation algorhythm that would iterate tons of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need a method call to `matches()`:

```
if (myString.matches(".*\\b" + anInteger + "\\b.*"))
    // string contains the number
```

This works using by creating a regex that has a word boundary (`\b`) at either end of the target number. The leading and trailing `.*` are required because `matches()` must match the *whole* string to return true.

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what i was searching for.

Answer (score 1):

Look into how to split a String into an array of String. So:

```
String[] splitStrings = myString.split(",")
ArrayList<Integer> parsedInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (String str : splitStrings) {
  parsedInts.add(Integer.parseInt(str));
}
```

then in your for loop:

```
if (parsedInts.contains(i)) {
  // body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
    String myString = "0,1,2,10,14,";
    String[] split = myString.split(",");
    for (String string : split) {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(string);
        if (num == 4) {
            System.out.println(num);
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: After type cast from string to int,y u r checking the value equal to 4 ??

Answer (score 0):

```
  String myString = "0,1,2,10,14,2323232";
   String[] allList = myString.split(",");
    for (String string : allList) {
         if(string.matches("[0-9]*"))
         {
             System.out.println("Its number with value "+string);
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pick all the numbers in the given string and find the permutation.

I think you need to Tokenize the given string with the Comma Separator.
When I do such program, I divide my logic to parse the String and write the logic in another method. Below is the snippet

```
String myString = "0,1,2,10,14,";
StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(myString , ",");

while (st2.hasMoreElements()) {
    doSomething(st2.nextElement());
}
```